# Java String.format() no me funciona

Tags: java, string, formato

Pretendo imprimir la cabecera de una tabla donde a continuación quiero insertar datos, pero String.format() no me funciona, tampoco funciona el mismo formato en System.out.printf aunque en otras ocasiones si me ha funcionado. Pero no veo la diferencia.
Mi código es este:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.printf("%-15s %-40s %-10 %9-s\n", "Codigo Producto", "Nombre Producto", "Precio", "Cantidad");
        
        String patron = "%-15s  %-40s %-10 %9-s\n";
        String codP = "Codigo Producto";
        String pre = "Precio";
        String nomP = "Nombre Producto";
        String cant = "Cantidad";
        String str = String.format(patron, codP, nomP, pre, cant);
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

Comment: tu linea de formato están mal escritas debería ser `"%-15s %-40s %-10s %-9s\n"` [algunos ejemplos](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un error de sintaxis, es todo.

Tu código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.printf("%-15s %-40s %-10 %9-s\n", "Codigo Producto", "Nombre Producto", "Precio", "Cantidad");
    
    String patron = "%-15s  %-40s %-10 %9-s\n";
    String codP = "Codigo Producto";
    String pre = "Precio";
    String nomP = "Nombre Producto";
    String cant = "Cantidad";
    String str = String.format(patron, codP, nomP, pre, cant);
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Específicamente en esta línea:

```
String patron = "%-15s  %-40s %-10 %9-s\n";
```

Después del 10 debes colocar el identificador de formato, que es 's' y quitar el '-' después del 9; quedando así:

```
String patron = "%-15s  %-40s %-10s %9s\n";
```

Comment: Vale si era error al escribir elcódigo pero no sabía leer la excepcion. Gracias